# combine every 7th value from a data set for averaging

Tags: php

I have a large dataset of values, representing daily figures.

I need to group these in groups of 7 and add them up, so that I can show averages per day of the week, where the user can ask to see averages over X days.

X can be any whole number, and might not be a multiple of 7.

So, if X is 14, then I need to take $data01 to $data14, and calculate like this:

```
$weekday1 = (($data01 + $data08) / 2);
$weekday2 = (($data02 + $data09) / 2);
$weekday3 = (($data03 + $data10) / 2);
$weekday4 = (($data04 + $data11) / 2);
$weekday5 = (($data05 + $data12) / 2);
$weekday6 = (($data06 + $data13) / 2);
$weekday7 = (($data07 + $data14) / 2);
```

I can then plot $weekday1 to $weekday7 on a graph.

if X was 20, then I would do:

```
$weekday1 = (($data01 + $data08 + $data15) / 3);
$weekday2 = (($data02 + $data09 + $data16) / 3);
$weekday3 = (($data03 + $data10 + $data17) / 3);
$weekday4 = (($data04 + $data11 + $data18) / 3);
$weekday5 = (($data05 + $data12 + $data19) / 3);
$weekday6 = (($data06 + $data13 + $data20) / 3);
$weekday7 = (($data07 + $data14) / 2);
```

I am struggling to get a neat solution that can work for any value of X. I currently have a solution, but it only works if X is a multiple of 7.

I am writing in php.

Comment: are you familiar with the modulo operator (`%`) ? You will definately need this for your solution

Comment: This data is static or in a DB?

Comment: Data comes from a DB. It changes every day.

Comment: how do you fetch the data from the DB? can you show us?

Comment: The database doesn't hold this as raw data - it holds a selection of data sources, and this $data01, etc, is computed in earlier code. So these values come from the DB, but can't be extracted directly from the DB.